# What happened internally here? 

Tags: java, oop

```
class A
{
    int i=10;
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println("show()");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    int j=20;
    void show1()
    {
        System.out.println("show1()");
    }
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        A a1=new B();//What happened internally here.please give me answer.
        a1.show();
        a1.show1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try and be more specific please? Your question is very broad and vague.

Comment: To understand that you should first learn what object orientation and POLYMORPHISM is.

Comment: @user: Please explain what you mean by "internally"? Do you mean the JVM bytecode? Do you mean the interpreter? Do you mean the garbage collector? Do you mean the compiler?

Answer (score 7):

```
A a1=new B();//What happened internally here.please give me answer.
a1.show();
a1.show1();
```

What happened is that you created an instance of `B` and assigned the reference to an variable of type `A`.  That's OK, because a `B` instance *is a* `A`.

In the next line you called one of the `A` methods on the `B` instance.  That's OK.

In the last line you attempted to call a `B` method.  But since the static type of `a1` is `A` that results in a compilation error.  However, if you had written the following, it would have compiled and run just fine.

```
((B) a1).show1();
```

---

If this doesn't answer your question, please rephrase it so that we can understand it better.

Answer (score 2):

Happened that you shouldn't be able to call:

```
a1.show1();
```

because even if a1 instance type is B (new B()), you are treating it like an A object, which hasn't the show1 method defined.