# what happened to below code with respect to compiler and Interpreter

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened internally here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853714/what-happened-internally-here)

```
class A
{
    int i=10;
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println("show()");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    int j=20;
    void show1()
    {
        System.out.println("show1()");
    }
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        A a1=new B();//What happened internally here.please give me answer.
        a1.show();
        a1.show1();
    }
}
```

Comment: how about getting answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853714/what-happened-internally-here

Comment: looks like post from same user. Voting to close.

Comment: If you don't understand the answers to your previous posting of this question, update the question and or comment on the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it as "giving a dog to someone who wants an animal" if it helps you =)

Answer (score 0):

New instance of class B will be created . The reference of type A will point to this class. A can hold reference of class B because the A's functionality is a subset of B's functionality (that is what the *extends* keyword says). Is there anything tricky here?

Answer (score 0):

Internally:

1. a reference of type A was created
2. An object of type B was created, allocating memory for its attributes
3. The address of the newly created Object was assigned to a1

Assignment of this type is possible since B inherits from A and therefore an Object of type B is also that of type A.